# Escape characters are getting added to JSON object

Tags: java, json, apache-commons

I have created a json object with json string. Once object is created i'm manipulating it's values. problem if my value contains html tag like "`</p>`" it converts it into "`<\/p>`".

Is there anyway to avoid it. Here is my code

```
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject;
import com.cloudwords.org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

public class EscapeText {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"text\": \"value11\",\"rte\": \"this <p>is</p> RTE\"}");
        jsonObj.put("rte", "Diese<p>ist</p>RTE");
        jsonObj.put("text", "value11");
        System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(jsonObj.toString()));
    }
}
```

Output is :- `{"text":"value11","rte":"Diese<p>ist<\/p>RTE"}`
Expected output :- `{"text":"value11","rte":"Diese<p>ist</p>RTE"}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is described in `JSONStringer.string(String)` method.

This behavior is wrong. I suggest you to use different JSON library.

Comment: Which one ? i tried GSON and response is not correct .    JsonObject o = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
  o.addProperty("rte", "Diese<p>ist</p>RTE");
  o.addProperty("text", "value11");
  Gson gsonObj = new Gson();
  System.out.println(gsonObj.toJson(o)); output is "{"text":"value11","rte":"Diese\u003cp\u003eist\u003c/p\u003eRTE"}"

Comment: I'm usually use `jackson`. I tried your example with it and it works.

Comment: yes it's working for me also. i user obj.toString() now its working fine. Thanks for your help

Comment: Note that the behavior is not "wrong" in sense of "this behavior yields invalid JSON". The JSON output is still valid, according to the JSON specification, see [json.org](https://www.json.org/).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are using `unescapeXML` which works subtly differently to escape characters in JSON. I believe you should be using `unescapeJSON` in your println.

Comment: It is happens before `unescapeXML` is invoked.